# iPhone NSMain Bundle Resources

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, core-data, nsbundle

I want to lock the main bundle resources in my app.. I have database added in my resource folder and I want to lock that so no one can access or read the database from outside the app. like some .bin type conversion on files? and decrypt them into the app? any help?

Comment: if device is jailbreak then anyone access your resources folder otherwise it is not posible in iphone.

Comment: without jailbreak you unzip the ipa and access the resources folder directly on your computer ;-)

Comment: how to lock them then? .txt files? or we have to encrypt the content?

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to use encryption, but be prepared for paperwork for the government.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, on a normal iPhone, nobody can see your bundle data. On a jailbroken phone however, one could easily extract your persistent store and use it.

Therefore, you need to encrypt your persistent store, i.e. the sql file itself. This can be done by passing the appropriate options when creating the persistent store:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"database.sqlite"];
    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath ];

    NSError *error = nil;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
        // Handle error
    }

    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:NSFileProtectionComplete forKey:NSFileProtectionKey];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] setAttributes:fileAttributes ofItemAtPath:storePath error:&error]) {
        // Handle error
    }

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: you don't need a jailbreak to access the bundle content, you can do that directly on a computer. .ipa files can be unzipped with the regular zip tools. And in that ipa file you will find an .app folder with all the resources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... but what if application we download directly to our desktop... resource bundles are easily accessable... what about our .txt files? can it be locked? or we have to apply encryption on that?

Comment: yes thats what I was saying any idea how to lock them? or we have to apply encryption on those files? like text files?